# Entity Framework through WCF Generates Backing Fields

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-5

I'm new to EF 5 (Switching from LINQ to SQL).

1. I did auto generate an .edmx based on my Database within my WCF project.
2. I did update my windows client which point to this same WCF service to auto generate all the entities on the client.

My issue is that the generation process appends `__BackingField` to all properties.

For example

`User.Name` within my WCF service becomes `User.Name__BackingField` on my client

My entities generated through LINQ to SQL did not had this problem.

Any help to remove that `__BackingField` is appriciated

Thanks,

Mathieux

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was causing the issue.

I had some of my entities extended with partial classes which where inheriting from [serializable].

Removing the [serializable] from my own partial classes resolved the issue.